# " I found her tiring and depressing " is this sentence correct?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, adjectives, participles

I found this sentence in my exam, I would like to know that my answer is correct or not.
Actually I should answer " tired and depressed "

Comment: Who was tired and depressed, you or her?

Comment: Depends on context. "I found her tiring and depressing" would be said if you mean she makes YOU feel tired and depressed. "I found her tired and depressed" means that when you found her, SHE was tired and depressed.

Answer (score 1):

Depress is a transitive verb, requiring an object. Tire may be transitive or intransitive.

Hence “I tire” makes intransitive sense (I am tiring somehow), but “I depress” is incomplete, lacking an object.

Now let us consider your sentence.

“I found her tiring” may mean that she was becoming tired or it may mean that you found her (to be a) tiring (gerundial adjective) (person).

“I found her depressing” can only mean that you found her (to be a) depressing (gerundial adjective) person. You did not find her to be depressing (a button, for example).

Because tiring and depressing occur in the same gerundial adjectival phrase “tiring and depressing”, the only acceptable meaning is that both are used in the transitive manner, that being the only verbal mode common to both.

A long-winded answer that concludes that the sentence is correct if you mean she was a person who both tired and depressed you.